# Impossible to use virtual keyword on destructor

Tags: c++

Is there any valid and usable case, that will force you not to use the `virtual` keyword before the destructor.

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() { ... } // `virtual` causes error (not compile time or syntax) or wrong behaviour
  // could contain other fields

};

// some example
```

Comment: I don't understand. You use `virtual` when you need it. You do not use `virtual` when you do not need it.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Perhaps you should ask about that directly instead?

Comment: The question, if I understood it correctly, is the opposite one: "When *not* to use virtual destructors?"

Comment: I mean a case, where you will be forced to remove `virtual` from a destructor. It will not give any compiler/syntax errors but will cause wrong behaviour.

Comment: "Wrong behavior" is also something you could ask about here. Create a [mcve] that replicates the "wrong behavior" and post a new question about it.

Comment: If the Base class is not intended to be used as a way to destruct derived classes, then a non-virtual protected destructor would be warranted.  (Other languages may calls such classes an `interface`, but C++ doesn't distinguish between the two as part of the core language.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that making the destructor `virtual` could convert your `class` from a non-polymorphic type to a polymorphic type.

Note that a polymorphic type is never *trivially copyable*. So, for example, you could break any use of `std::memcpy` by the introduction of a virtual destructor.

In some situations - particularly when interoperating with C - that can wreak havoc, as you can no longer assume that the address of an instance of your `class` is the same as the address of the first member.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: You mean, that the problem comes not from the virtuality of the destructor, but the virtuality itself. Am I right?

Comment: @arsdever: Yes. The destructor is the means by which your type becomes virtual if it wasn't already.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any valid and usable case, that will force you not to use the virtual keyword before the destructor.

Yes. If you ever use `std::memcpy` or `std::memcmp` with instances of the class or its members, or rely on a pointer to/from an instance being convertible to the first member of the class,or examine common initial sequence of an inactive union member of the class type.

In general: If you rely on the class being a standard-layout type or trivially copyable, then the destructor (as well as all other member functions) must be non-virtual. Most cases of erroneously assuming standard-layoutness or triviality have undefined behaviour. Those properties can be enforced with type traits and static asserts, so that you get a nice compilation error instead.